# Can someone give translation to Arya Durga Ashtakam?

Tags: translation-request, durga, shakti, stotra

This is the Arya Durga Ashtakam-

> [**Arya Durga Ashtakam**](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/AryAdurgAShTakam.html?lang=sa)

Kindly give its translation.

Comment: I think no one translated it into English.

Comment: @TheDestroyer yes, I did not find any. I tried to comprehend its meaning, but the composer AnantaKavi has used very intricate Sanskrita.